# ANTLR - Populate a Java class while parsing the input message

Tags: java, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

How can I, using **ANTLR**, populate a class of mine while I'm parsing the input message?

For example, if my input message is: **name = Paul AND age = 16 AND country = china;**

While I'm parsing this message, can I perform, in the Grammar file, something like:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setName("Paul");
p.setAge("16");
p.setCountry("china");
```

Where **Person.java** is a class that I built. Or this can only be made in the main Java class where I print the AST?

Comment: yes you can but if this is only what you need to do,you dont need antlr

Comment: OK. But is there any specific syntax for this? To write this in the Grammar file?

Comment: if this `name = Paul AND age = 16 AND country = china;` is all what you want to parse, then all what you need to do is get rid off `';'` character from end of line, split your line on `"AND"`, you can use `String.split()` then each entry in your array split again on `'='`. Then by using reflection get your setter from instance and set right parameter. do you want create instance of your class, source or binary file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create instance of your class from `name = Paul AND age = 16 AND country = china` that kind of script, then you could create yourself method

```
public <T> T builder(Class<T> clazz, String line)
            throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        T instance = clazz.newInstance();
        String[] exps = line.split("AND");
        for (String exp : exps) {

            String[] tokens = exp.split("=", 2);
            // TODO check if token has length==2
            tokens[0] = tokens[0].trim();
            tokens[1] = tokens[1].trim();
            String methodName = "set"
                    + (("" + tokens[0].charAt(0)).toUpperCase())
                    + tokens[0].substring(1);
            Method m1 = instance.getClass().getMethod(methodName, String.class);
            m1.invoke(instance, tokens[1]);
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

and when you call it `builder(Person.class,"name = Paul AND age = 16 AND country = china")` you will get instance of `Person` class with populated fields `name`, `age` and `country`.

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Something like that... But I found out that is better to parse the generated AST than the input message in runtime.